# How to set a bookmark on a number in MS Word (2007)?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to put a version number in my document (e.g. `1.0`, `2.3.4`), and I want it to be reflected in other places in the document. I followed some instructions to [create custom file properties using a bookmark](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP051897551033.aspx), but when creating a bookmark for `1.0`, the bookmark ends at the dot, and when the number is updated only the part before the dot is reflected. Is it possible to make the bookmark span the whole number, including multiple dots if they exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update the version number by positioning the cursor to the right of "1.0" and pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete the "0", then you are accidentally truncating the bookmark. When you type the second "1" to make the document version 1.1, the "1" does not get added to the bookmark--it's just treated as regular text.

To get around this:

1. Click after the dot and before the 0, so it looks like "1.|0"
2. Type the 1, making the version number "1.10"
3. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete the 0, leaving "1.1" as the value of the bookmark.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2007 I would not use a bookmark for this as they are much less flexible than the new content controls.

Insert > Quick Parts > Document property > pick something appropriate.

While there is no "version" property, you could use something like "status". This gives you a content control to type in.
Next time you add another control of the same type, the text matches.

The big advantage of these is that the content is part of the document properties (metadata), so if you change any one of them, they all update instantly, rather than with a bookmark you have to update the parent one, then the cross-references update. Also if you delete the original bookmark by mistake, the whole thing breaks; you delete one content control and the rest still work, and you just add one back in when you need it.

You can customise and extend these as well. Best reference work is Stephanie Krieger's [Advanced Office Documents 2007 edition](http://www.arouet.net/mmod.html)

Comment: Thank you for this useful information. However, I need to retain compatibility with DOC files, and quick parts are not compatible.